# repos/{org}/{repo}/git/trees/{sha} to query files in repo returns element with type=commit - how to deal with that?

Tags: github-api, git-submodules

I have some code to retrieve a list of files from a repository (using REST API v3) and it worked great for many cases, but now I've hit a problem where it didn't work. Looking into this, I found that one of the elements of the response had this:

```
{
        "mode": "160000",
        "path": "folderA/folderB/folderC",
        "sha": "84419db012d987a1705eea28055b278c17411a93",
        "type": "commit"
    }
```

If I look at that path using the browser, the folder is shown as:
[image] - so after some confusion and embarrassement, I looked at things and concluded this must be a submodule (indeed it is mentioned in `/.gitmodules`.

I wonder how to best deal with that when I want to retrieve everything: currently my plan is to use `path`-entry to find a matching `[submodule "path"]` and then retrieve the tree from the repo using ther `url` from `.gitmodules` and `sha` from the response that I quoted. There is a `path` in `.gitmodules`, too - I guess that's just redundant?  (Would be grateful for any other comments and suggestions. Maybe there is an easier approach to get thinghs?)

Also, I did not find doc about this - so is submodule the only reason for having `commit` in the respone, or could there be other cases to consider?

Update: it worked as I described! But I'm really concerned I might be hit by other unexpected items in the reply, so the question is really about documentation regarding the items in a response to querying the tress-API.

Comment: I see that one person votes "close" stating that details were lacking. It would be helpful to know WHICH details you're missing - I'm happy to give whatever info is needed!